# A better way to make this "Pac-Man" shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make an image that essentially a grey circle with a white Pac Man inside.  The problem is the Pac Man seems to have a curve connecting his upper and lower lip, and I want to hide that.  My version is below, which I made in Geogebra.

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{ffffff}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw [line width=0.4pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.5] (0.0,0.0) circle (2.0cm);
\draw [color=ffffff,fill=ffffff,fill opacity=1.0] (0.0,0.0) circle (1.0cm);
\draw (0.0,3.0)-- (0.0,-3.0);
\draw (-3.0,0.0)-- (3.0,0.0);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (0.0,-1.0)-- (0.0,0.0);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (0.0,0.0)-- (1.0,0.0);
\draw [shift={(0,0)},line width=.01pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.5]  (0,0) --  plot[domain=-1.5707963267948966:0.0,variable=\t]({cos(\t r)},{sin(\t r)}) -- cycle ;
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black,shift={(0.0,3.0)}] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
\draw [fill=black,shift={(0.0,-3.0)},rotate=180] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
\draw [fill=black,shift={(-3.0,0.0)},rotate=90] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
\draw [fill=black,shift={(3.0,0.0)},rotate=270] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which yields the aforementioned curve.

[image]

I assume the issue is with the line

```
\draw [shift={(0,0)},line width=.01pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.5]  (0,0) --  plot[domain=-1.5707963267948966:0.0,variable=\t]({cos(\t r)},{sin(\t r)}) -- cycle ;
```

I have tried things like `opacity=0`, or `color=7F7F7F`, but it always ends up either black or white.

Comment: Your MWE doesn't contain used packages and definitions of colors. Can you provide a sketch of "pac-man". Please, edit your question. And welcome to SE!

Comment: @Zarko Forgive me if the cultural reference of Pac Man is not clear.  In the image I have posted, I am simply trying to get rid of the white curve that cuts through the grey area. I edited the MWE so it works now.

Answer (score 6):

This is a simplified version of you code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=0.4pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.5] (0,0) circle (2);
  \fill[white] (0,0) -- (1,0) arc[radius=1,start angle=0,delta angle=270] -- (0,0);
  \draw[<->] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
  \draw[<->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: rendering]

The arrows are not exactly the same as in your example, you should have a look at the `arrows.meta` TikZ library.

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  I couldn't care less about the arrows; I just use what Geogebra offers, usually.  Thanks!

Comment: Or `\filldraw[line width=0.4pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.5,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (2) (1,0) arc (0:270:1) -- (0,0) --cycle;`

Answer (score 1):

For fun, a short code in `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}


\begin{document}

\psset{arrowinset=0, labels = none, ticks=none, fillstyle=solid}
\begin{pspicture}%
    \pscircle[linecolor=SlateGray, fillcolor=LightSlateGrey!75]{2}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=white, linestyle=none]{1}{0}{270}
    \psaxes[arrows=<->, linecolor=SlateGray] (0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]